# Getting AngularJS $route to redirect to a specific state

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-service

I have specific viewing states that I want users to be able to link to.

I'm trying to route a controller to a specific state of the page when a user goes to `http://localhost:3000/resource/#!/1`

My configuration is:

```
   $routeProvider.when('/:memberId', {
      controller: 'MemberDetailsCtrl'
    });
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
```

I've been experimenting a lot and it seems like $route is undefined until all the scopes are done generating. That means I can't execute

`$http.get('/resource/' + $route.current.params.memberId + '.json')`

in the controller / service and trigger that particular state by checking the route params.

I've been able to do all of this using regex and `$location.path()` inside my controller but maybe there's a better way? (using ngView is not flexible enough)

## IMPORTANT UPDATE

Nowadays there is a great module — [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which helps manage routes, states and views much better than default $routeProvider.

Comment: Try injecting `$routeParams` instead of `$route` into your controller, then use `$routeParams.memberId` in your get() call.

Comment: I tried and sadly, I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just setting up a watch function for the route change broadcast from within the controller:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $http.get('/resource/' + $scope.params.memberId +'.json').success(function (d) {$scope.jsresponse = d;});
  });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtuKv/2/)